# .NET How to concurrently process API stream of json objects

Tags: .net, twitter, concurrency, message-queue

I'm building a small demo application to generate statistics based on tweets from [Twitter's Sample Stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/sampled-stream/introduction) endpoint. Every second Twitter dumps a payload of tweets based on whatever API parameters are provided. I want to take these payloads and dump them into a queue for processing. I want to build this with concurrency in mind for scalability. Would something like a Message Queue be overkill for this or is there a better pattern to follow?

Answer (score 0):

A message queue could be a good solution. The reason is that the tweets can arrive so fast and you don't want the thread that reads the stream to be engaged in any other processing. If the code doesn't respond in time, the Twitter stream might disconnect and you'll need to reconnect. There's also a rate limit on reconnections, so a worst-case scenario would make it hard to maintain a connection and lose tweets. Having the Queue makes it easy to dump the tweet on the queue and get back to reading the stream. On the other side of the queue, you can add some concurrent code that processes the tweets efficiently.